# MIPS Pipeline - solve data hazard

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

Given this piece of MIPS assembly:

```
slti $t1, $t2, 24
add  $t4, $t1, $t3
sub  $t5, $t4, $t1
sw   $t1, 150($t4)
subi $t3, $t5, 1
lw   $t1, 30($t2)
```

The question is to find all the hazard in this code(RAW, WAW, WAR):

RAW slti - add
RAW slti - sub
RAW add - sub
WAW add - sw
RAW sub - subi

First thing first, i have no idea if this is actually correct, especially what confuse me is that there are 0 WAR, can someone post an example of a WAR hazard?

The second point of the exercise asks to execute the code and put stall where it is needed (the pipeline has forwarding)

My solution has 0 stall because each of this problem can be solved with forwarding.

```
SLTI F D E M W
ADD    F D E M W
SUB      F D E M W
SW         F D E M W
SUBI         F D E M W
LW             F D E M W
```

Please, someone explain

Comment: A classic MIPS only runs 1 instruction per clock, and with proper hazard-detection and forwarding only has a problem with load instructions, specifically using a load result in the instruction after it.  (Or with `mult` / `div` / `mflo` / `mfhi`).  But your LW is last, so indeed there are no stalls, only forwarding.  Weird that they'd ask that.

Comment: There are potential WAR hazards on $t3 read by ADD, written by SUBI (which must actually be an ADDI `-1` since MIPS only has SUBI as a pseudo-instruction supported by some assemblers.)  And over a shorter distance, SW reads `$t1`, LW writes `$t1`.  Normally WAR hazards aren't a problem for an in-order pipeline anyway, though, especially not when all the ALU operations have single-cycle latency so the read won't still be waiting to read some previous ALU result when the write is ready.  I guess waiting to read a cache-miss load could be a thing with a non-blocking cache (and load scoreboarding)

Comment: In most of these exercises about inserting NOPs for RAW hazards, they want you pretend there is no forwarding, so maybe reread the assignment text.